# C printf term progress display with error messages on next line

Tags: c, terminal

For a long running task I'd like to have a progress display. I'm currently using `\33[2K\r` at the start of my `printf` command, and no newline or anything at the end. What I don't like about this approach is that messages printed to the same terminal (`stderr` without redirection for example) appear at the end of the line, instead of a new one.

If I put the `\r` at the end of the progress display, other messages (all terminated with `\n`) would visually override the progress display and get mixed up with remains if they are shorter than that. Also, I don't want to have to/can't adapt the lines printing those other messages, as some of them come from external libraries.

I don't have a problem if my progress display would continue on a new line afterwards, but I'd like to have other messages appearing on their own line (mostly error messages, but I'm trying to gracefully recover as much as possible, so the process will continue most of the time)

Any Ideas?

I don't need portability, it's fine with me if it only runs on linux bash.

Upd: For better visualization of what I'm asking for:

Currently I can do:

```
status1ERR
status2
```

Or

```
ERRtus1
status2
```

Or

```
status1
status2  <--- ERR is overriden by status2 here
```

But what I want is:

```
status1
ERR
status2
```

Or

```
ERR      
status2
```

In the last example ERR overrides a complete status line - I know I can clear lines with the aforementioned VT100 character sequence, but I can't change some of the error messages, so it needs to work with them always being of the format `error message\n`

Comment: Print status line with "status, \r\n".  Then each subsequent status line (that does not have some other normal printf that occurred) with "cursor up, status, \r\n".

Comment: thought about that as well, but in case there was an error, I would override it automatically with the next status in that case :(

Answer (score 1):

Wow. This is a blast from my past.

You can use ANSI or VT100 character sequences to do some cursor positioning.
That will let you separate the types of output on the screen.
Here's a good starter page: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

Comment: I'm already using a VT100 character sequence to erase the line (it's in my question ;) ) - so, while your answer is nice, it doesn't answer my question :( Let me rephrase that: How would I use those character sequences to accomplish what I asked for?

Comment: Use the cursor up, down, forward, backward commands to position the cursor before sending the output. Position the status and and output in different places on the screen and you should be good.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve, but _how_ would I do that? As you see in my examples, I've already tried various ways I could think of, but they don't lead me to the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `\n` at the beginning of the error messages. This - of course - doesn't work if you call some other code that produces stderr-output, too.

Comment: That's exactly the problem - I don't have control over all the error messages.

Comment: Then you might capture stderr on your own, output a `\n` to stdout, the just echoing it to the original stderr (dirty trick).

Comment: Sounds like a lot of trouble for such a simple problem - also, if the part in between could fail for whatever reason, that'd be a problem in it's own. I just can't really imagine that there is no simple solution to this ... ?